# How do I make this string into a list in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and I just want to know how to change the below string1 to a list.

Input string: `string1 = Hello`

Output list:  `to_list = [H, E, L, L, O]`

Comment: How to turn the string into all caps will be left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. My bad :) I retracted it. By the way, the link provided above does not answer the caps part. Anyway, @Meeraz: `print (list(String1.upper()))`

Comment: [s.upper() for s in String1]
Out[28]: ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']

Comment: Another implementation: `[x.upper() for x in list(string1)]` returns `['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']`